# Using Excel Double Value in C#

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, double

I'm trying to get double values from Excel to my C# project. But, when I try that, Visual Studio automatically erases the comma/period, and shows the number without them.

For Example:

Excel: 192,168 or 192.168

C#: 192168,00

How can I prevent this from happening?

Excel Get-Value Code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; i++)
{
   for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; j++)
   {
      tsp.addArray(Convert.ToDouble(ds.Tables["Deneme"].Rows[i][j].ToString()), i, j);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace is good way to do it i guess.

Just try like that.

```
string oldString = ds.Tables["Deneme"].Rows[i][j].ToString(); // Old string in addArray.
string convertedString = oldString.Replace(".",","); // Replacer for dots.
double convertedDouble = Convert.ToDouble(convertedString); // Convert double now.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your culture is `tr-TR` that's why your [`NumberDecimalSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is `,` not `.`

That's why when you write 192.168 in your program, it read its as *hundred and ninety-two thousand ...* but when you write 192,168 *hundred and ninety-two ...*

If your excel cell is like `192,168`, there is no problem. [`Convert.ToDouble`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1hkw6k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) works exactly as you want;

```
string s = "192,168";
double d = Convert.ToDouble(s, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("tr-TR"));
Console.WriteLine(d); //192,168
```

But if your excel cell is like `192.168`, then you need to use `n0` format like;

```
string s = "192.168";
double d = 0;
if(s.Contains("."))
{
    d = Convert.ToDouble(s, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("tr-TR"));
}
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("n0")); //192.168
```